# JQuery background-image won't display

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a background image from JQuery. 
 I tried like everything but my the background-image won't show.

My code (example):

```
$(function() {
    var cssObj = 
    {
        'background-image' : 'url(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png)'
    }

    $('.Main').css(cssObj);
});

<div class="Main"></div>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/334N7/5/

Comment: It works [http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/x7B5L/](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/x7B5L/). You did not select "jquery" framework on the left in your fiddle.

Comment: @daageu. You have a javascript error on your website (check the console). As @gion_13 mentionned in his answer, you should remove the single quotes within `url()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and it works. The problem is that your div is empty and has no height.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9C/2/)

```
<div class="Main" style="height:100px; width:100px"></div>
```

#### Update

Your **jsFiddle** does not work because your forgot to set `jQuery` as the framework

Here is your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/334N7/15/)

### Update

I have checked your site. The reason why it does not works is that the image `arrowright.png` is not there or at another path. It results in a

> **"GET daangeudens.be/arrowright.png 404 (Not Found)"**

**Change**

```
$(function() {
    var cssObj = 
    {
        'background-image' : 'url(../arrowright.png)',
    }

    $('.Main').css(cssObj);
});
```

**to**

```
$(function() {
    var cssObj = 
    {
        'background-image' : 'url(/img/arrowright.png)',
    }

    $('.Main').css(cssObj);
});
```

Comment: I think the asker edited their question after @gion_13 answerd it for them.

Comment: Yes i don't saw the jsFiddle first. But my answer is updated and cover both, the sample and his jsFiddle.

Comment: Mmm the image was on the ftp but couldn't load it strange... now it works ty ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In your fiddle, you have another set of quotes surrounding the image link. remove them. :

```
'url(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png)'
```

instead of

```
 'url('http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png')'
```

And also, select the **jquery** framework in the fiddle.
Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/334N7/14/)